# Manage different pdf file header with single library file - TCPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I have to create around 10-12 pdf using TCPDF.

For this,I have downloaded TCPDF and added it to third party folder (I am using codeigniter) and Pdf.php file to library folder (which manage header and footer of pdf).

Now,as I said before,Header and Footer managing from this pdf.php file,but I want different header in my different pdf file whereas i have pdf.php is a single file in my library which defines format of header and foote .

So,how can I manage different header for different pdf with single pdf.php file in library.

Please help !!

Comment: `if ($x) {$header =$y} else{ ..`

Comment: sorry but can you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make different library file (same like your pdf.php with require changes in header) and store it with other name in library folder.

And just add this library file to your php file with load library (as you said you using codeigniter) with the help of $this->load->library('newpdf');